# How can I remove the standard icon from <apex:sectionHeader>?

Tags: visualforce, apexpage

This is part of my VF page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="DataRetentionExt">
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$Label.DataRetention}" />
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
```

I do not use tabStyle attribute and I need to remove the standard icon:
[image]

Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 1):

The image is because you are using `apex:sectionHeader` and default image and title is showing.

Don't use `apex:sectionHeader` and use standard HTML tag like `<h1>` or `<h2>` to display the title.

Like:

```
<h1>{!$Label.DataRetention}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution seems to me very bad.

Comment: There could be many solutions for a given use case, until & unless you think all the areas you cannot consider a solution is very bad.

Comment: I tried to use your solution, but the header, even with tag <h1> looks very small.

Comment: You should incorporate any style suitable for this.